# Java how to represent empty Integer in JSON

Tags: java, json

I have to represent in JSON null `Integer` in this way `score:` . Show name of the attribute and empty space if `Integer` is null. Now if `Integer` is null, then JSON doesn't show attribute. Is it possible to do it with `Integer`?

Comment: An "empty space" isn't a valid JSON value. It would really help if you could show an example of the JSON you want to end up with - along with a [mcve] that doesn't work for you. (At the moment we don't know which library you're using to create the JSON, for example.)

Comment: I don't think it's possible (you need to have something in your json that represent `null`, so that programs can actually parse the files. However, I'm not 100% confident in this

Comment: You can just omit some fields in JSON object

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to leave a property value empty in `JSON`.

The possible value type for the fields are:

[image]

Set your variable to something distinctable like -1 or something.

Answer (score 0):

JSON represents data as name/value pairs. There must be a value present if the name is present.   See [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) for the complete syntax.

A null can be represented by specifying null ...

```
{name: "Steve", score : null}
```

... or by omitting the name 'score' from the JSON ...

```
{name : "Steve"}
```